# Erro ao fazer npm install no meu projeto ionic

Tags: node.js, ionic, ionic2, npm

Quando dou o comando npm install no projeto me mostra esse erro, o que pode ser ?

---

```html
bash-3.2$ npm install
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: @angular/compiler@2.9
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget 0.0.0-0, 0.0.0-1, 0.0.0-2, 0.0.0-3, 0.0.0-4, 0.0.0-5, 0.0.0-6, 0.0.0-7, 2.0.0-rc.0, 2.0.0-rc.1, 2.0.0-rc.2, 2.0.0-rc.3, 2.0.0-rc.4, 2.0.0-rc.5, 2.0.0-rc.6, 2.0.0-rc.7, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0-
beta.0, 2.0.2, 2.1.0-rc.0, 2.1.0, 2.2.0-beta.0, 2.1.1, 2.2.0-beta.1, 2.1.2, 2.2.0-rc.0, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.3.0-beta.0, 2.2.2, 2.3.0-beta.1, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.3.0-rc.0, 2.3.0, 4.0.0-beta.0, 2.3.1, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 4
.0.0-beta.1, 4.0.0-beta.2, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 4.0.0-beta.3, 2.4.4, 4.0.0-beta.4, 2.4.5, 4.0.0-beta.5, 2.4.6, 4.0.0-beta.6, 2.4.7, 4.0.0-beta.7, 2.4.8, 4.0.0-beta.8, 4.0.0-rc.0, 4.0.0-rc.1, 4.0.0-rc.2, 2.4.9, 4.0
.0-rc.3, 2.4.10, 4.0.0-rc.4, 4.0.0-rc.5, 4.0.0-rc.6, 4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.1.0-beta.0, 4.0.2, 4.1.0-beta.1, 4.0.3, 4.1.0-rc.0, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.2.0-beta.0, 4.1.2, 4.2.0-beta.1, 4.1.3, 4.2.0-rc.0
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'ionic-hello-world'
npm ERR! notarget

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/FelipeRicci/.npm/_logs/2017-05-22T12_32_05_250Z-debug.log
```

### E aqui esta as Informações do ionic

```html
bash-3.2$ ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1
ios-sim version: 5.0.13
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v7.10.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002
```

Comment: npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

Comment: Voce pode postar o seu package.json por favor?